# How to write this python post request in axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, python-requests

I have this post request written in python, which works just fine:

```py
import requests

requests.request(
    "POST", 
     "http://locahost:8086/parse", 
     data={
        "names": ["name1", "name2"],
        "surnames": ["surname1", "surname2"]
     },
     files=[
        ("choices", ("choices-1", open("file1.txt", "rb"))),
        ("choices", ("choices-2", open("file2.txt", "rb"))),
        ("references", ("references-1", open("file3.txt", "rb"))),
        ("references", ("references-2", open("file4.txt", "rb"))),

     ] 
)
```

The server application endpoint is written in **fastapi** and has the following structure:

```py
@app.post("/test")
async def test_endpoint(
    names: List[str] = Form(...),
    surnames: List[str] = Form(...),
    references: List[UploadFile] = File(...),
    choices: List[UploadFile] = File(...)
):
```

**My question is: How can I consume this endpoint in Node.js using axios?**

I tried with the following:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const FormData = require("form-data");

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("names", "name1");
formData.append("names", "name2");
formData.append("surnames", "surname1");
formData.append("surnames", "surname2");
formData.append("references", fs.createReadStream('file1.txt'));
formData.append("references", fs.createReadStream('file2.txt'));
formData.append("choices", fs.createReadStream('file3.txt'));
formData.append("choices", fs.createReadStream('file4.txt'));

axios.post("http://localhost:8086/parse", formData).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

But I've got the 422 error, I also tried to replace the `fs.createReadStream('file1.txt')` with `fs.readFileSync('file1.txt')` and `formData.append("names", '["name1", "name2"]')` but it did not work as well. Can someone help me out to make this post work?

Obs: The backend should accept a variable number of `names`, `surnames`, `references` and `choices`, that is why it is structured like this. I am also using the axios version 0.21 and node 10.19.0.

Comment: From the answer on the duplicate, scroll down to the section titled _"On Axios - NodeJS"_. You need to set the headers from the `FormData` instance